# travel restrictions associated with UK working visa

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I am an Italian citizen resident in the UK. My partner is a US citizen with a working visa in the UK that is due to be renewed in January 2016 (after 3 years). Is it correct that he can't leave the UK for more than 6 months within a year time if he wants to maintain his status (at least until he gets permanent residency)? If we get married, will he be allowed to have a spouse visa? In that case would there be any restrictions about leaving the UK for more than 6 months? Many thanks

Comment: How long have you two been partners? Have you considered him joining you as your partner according to http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=463 instead of with a working visa? It could be difficult to prove your partnership if you live separately for 6 months while he is overseas, and you run the risk of problems if the UK leaves the EU at the upcoming referendum, but it might be a solution to your specific problem.